# 2-parameter PreparedStatement is throwing syntax error, SQL State 42601, near second argument

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I am creating a simple java application that uses a postgresql database which I have already created (the database has been created, not the application).
One of the TABLEs is called 'Employee'.
It has an attribute called 'eid', short for employee id.

I am trying to use a PreparedStatement to generalize a database SELECT query. I want there to be two parameters which are generalized. I would also like to get the length of the result, so I created a second PreparedStatement to find that.

The code seems quite simple, but I keep getting the same syntax error.

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
    public static String[] select(Connection conn, String arguments) {

        try {

            PreparedStatement preparedSelect = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT ? FROM ?");
            PreparedStatement preparedCount = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ?");

            String[] arrOfStr = arguments.split(" ", 0);

            System.out.println(arrOfStr[0].equals("eid"));
            System.out.println(arrOfStr[1].equals("Employee"));

            preparedSelect.setString(1, arrOfStr[0]);
            preparedSelect.setString(2, arrOfStr[1]);
            preparedCount.setString(1, arrOfStr[1]);

            ResultSet rsSelect = preparedSelect.executeQuery();
            ResultSet rsCount = preparedCount.executeQuery();

            ...
```

In the first line's argument, I would like the SELECT query to be: "SELECT eid FROM Employee".
In the second line's argument, I would like the SELECT query to be: "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employee".

The user who uses this application enters (earlier in the program) the "arguments" argument found in the arguments of the "select" function. The "arrOfStr" string array will contain these two strings, "eid", and "Employee".

To check that "arrOfStr" has the correct values, I printed the booleans resulting from the .equals() function comparing the values to the strings I want which, again, are "eid", and "Employee".

In the console the results are, not to my surprise:

```
true
true
```

Thus, in the next 3 lines, I set the String values "eid" and "Employee" into the PreparedStatements.

Finally, I execute the queries in the following 2 lines. Both of these query executions (I have tried switching them around) give me a very similar error. For the given code I get the error:

```
SQL State: 42601
ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2"
  Position: 16
```

This is stating that there is an issue with the syntax of the string "Employee".

When I go directly to my postgresql database, and input:

```
SELECT eid FROM Employee;
```

I get the output:

```
1663
1983
1357
...
```

Could someone explain this syntax error?

Comment: You can't bind a table or column name in your query; that is not how prepared statements are implemented. `SELECT EID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE NAME=?` is allowed. You cannot put `?` just anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Elliott, you cannot bind the table name that way.

To achieve your goal, try this:

```
String[] arrOfStr = arguments.split(" ", 0);

PreparedStatement preparedSelect = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT ? FROM " + arrOfStr[1]);
PreparedStatement preparedCount = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + arrOfStr[1]);
```